# freepastry tutorial 3 error: Cannot join ring. All bootstraps are faulty

Tags: java, p2p, pastry

I try to learn how to use the FreePastry API for creating Peer to Peer application. Now, I working on the 3rd tutorial, but somehow I got this error message.

> Cannot join ring.  All bootstraps are faulty.

```
run:
Ox6FD69D:rice.pastry:20160628.044B23.402:joinFailed(rice.pastry.JoinFailedException: Cannot join ring. All boostraps are faulty.[/212.218.89.4:9001])
Usage:
Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Could not join the FreePastry ring. Reason:rice.pastry.JoinFailedException: Cannot join ring. All bootstraps are faulty.[/212.218.89.4:9001])
java [-cp FreePastry-<version>.jar] rice.tutorial.lesson3.DistTutorial localbindport bootIP bootPort
example java rice.tutorial.DistTutorial 9001 pokey.cs.almamater.edu 90001
        at rice.tutorial.lesson3.DistTutorial.<init>(DistTutorial.java:94)
        at rice.tutorial.lesson3.DistTutorial.main(DistTutorial.java:164)
BUILD STOPPED (total time: 46 seconds)
```

which "212.218.89.4" as my IP address? and the rest of the code is the same as the demo. Did I need to change something on the code? or I miss something??

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

It happended the same to me, but the error was because I was using 127.0.0.1 as my ip address. I use ipconfig command to get my ip and now it works fine.

I thought at the beggining the error was because they say that in your project you must have user.params or freepastry.params file, but at the end it works with the default constructor of the Environment. Check this https://trac.freepastry.org/wiki/tut_environment

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the IPv4 address of your computer.

Donot use the subnet mask address like 255.255.255.0

This error is mainly from the net address